# Getting variable constraint value

Tags: python, linear-programming, or-tools, scip, cp-sat

How would I find the constraint value of a variable using SAT_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING given a feasible solution. Essentially solution_value() but for constraint.

Looked through documentation and nothing that helps with that above

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using `pywraplp`, there is `ComputeConstraintActivities` which computes the sum of the linear terms of each constraint. Have a look at [linear_programming.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/5d764559566d6db01f7bcfa26ff79abfdfbfa880/examples/python/linear_programming.py#L122) for usage.

If you are using `model_builder`, then [this](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/5d764559566d6db01f7bcfa26ff79abfdfbfa880/ortools/linear_solver/python/model_builder.py#L1318) should be followed.

Comment: Am using pywraplp. What i was wondering if I can get the variable value given a constraint. Not the sum of all constraint variables

Comment: Makes no sense. Variables have one solution value independently of constraints